# Does "see you this weekend" in email express "will write another email this weekend"?

Tags: writing, expressions, email

Perhaps people will think that I'll physically visit them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any time I've ever said *see you this weekend*, I've meant that I would physically see that person. However, it is usually used when there are already plans in place. I would never write *see you this weekend* unless the recipient and I had made plans.

Answer (score 4):

No. It means you will actually see them with your eyes. It doesn't have to be a physical visit - it could be via a video chat.

It probably could also mean within an MMORPG, since you are seeing a representation of the person (their avatar).

Comment: I don't agree. I've never said 'I'll see you this weekend' for anything other than physical contact. I would say, 'I'll speak with you this weekend', or 'I'll call you this weekend' for a video chat. Maybe that's just me, though. It's very difficult to provide a precise definition for idioms such as this.

Comment: @JDOConal I'm not sure if this is an idiom, even though it may mean slightly different things to different people.

Comment: @Chris You may be right. What would you say an idiom is?

Comment: @JDOConal I think an idiom is a phrase that has a peculiar meaning in a specific language & culture. If you do a word-for-word translation of "see you this weekend" into a number of languages, the meaning is the same. There is no special meaning tied to this phrase that isn't plainly stated in its words.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's a fair enough assessment, but I think there is something which isn't plainly stated in the words -- e.g., looking at a photograph doesn't count. I think it actually means, 'I will be in your presence this weekend'. Of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: "See you this weekend." means a physical encounter. It is irrelevant how the words translate into other languages; the meaning of the phrase is a physical encounter. Granted you could say in an MMORPG, "See you this weekend." but in that case you are personifying your character.

Comment: @Pickle I understand your's and OConal's point of view. However, just because something doesn't exactly means what that words say, doesn't make it an idiom. If your definition of "See you this weekend" holds, then it *does* mean (at least) you will "see" them this weekend. This does not make this phrase an idiom (which was the point of bringing other languages into this).

Comment: @Chris It's not an idiom. It's the opposite of an idiom since the words mean precisely what they say. **An idiom is something that means the opposite of what the words mean** like, "You've got your work cut out for you." That should mean it's going to be easy since someone already cut out all your work; like a seamstress or tailor that has someone cut the cloth patterns for them and all that's left is sewing it together. So no, it is not even close to an idiom.

Comment: @Pickle I agree. Sorry that I misunderstood your original intent. :)

Answer (score 3):

I must admit that when text-chatting with people, I have on occasion said "See you later", which admittedly sounded (!) a bit weird, but "type to you later" sounded even more awkward. On the telephone, I would clearly say "speak to you later".

I guess a more accurate  alternative would be "chat with you later", or more generically "communicate with you later", but the "... to you later" formulation is very ingrained.

Answer (score 2):

I once read an article where a blind person was ok with the idiom, and was bemused when her able-bodied colleagues tried to avoid the phrase.

Comment: I have a blind friend who will often use the phrase "Hear you later" - but I think it is probably partly for comedic value as he also uses such interesting phrases as "Have a happy."

Answer (score 2):

I think "See you later" has become an idiom which is often exactly equivalent to "goodbye".  But "See you [at some specific time/place]" implies to me that we are going to meet.  If we have an appointment to meet online (chat room, video call, online-game, etc), I would understand your intent (and I would say this to someone else). However if I was going to write someone a message on the weekend I wouldn't say this. An email is not a meeting.