# Usage of the word "meet" in the context of a phone call/video conference

Tags: word-choice

Is it acceptable English to use the verb *meet* in the context of a phone call or a video conference?

To provide a bit of background, I am writing an email to a business associate overseas. There is little chance of an actual face-to-face meeting taking place anytime soon, however a phone call or a video conference would obviously work fine.

I don't want to be the one to suggest a method of communication, but would rather let the business associate decide in what way would they prefer to conduct the conversation. For this reason, I was thinking of using a neutral verb, e.g. *meet*. Can I use a phrase such as "I hope we can meet to discuss topic X in the near future" in the context of a phone call or a video conference?

Intuitively, I would say that this sounds a little awkward. Nevertheless, given the fact that phone conference calls are often referred to as meetings, I was thinking that this sort of usage of the word might be acceptable after all. What do you think?

Comment: How about _I hope we can find time to discuss. . ._?

Comment: Both are certainly acceptable. Neither sounds awkward. However, to me, “meet” at least slightly suggests a face-to-face meeting in a way that “have a meeting” doesn't. “I hope we can schedule a meeting to discuss X in the near future” is slightly clunkier than what you proposed, but if you're anxious to avoid the slightest misinterpretation, perhaps the extra words are worth it.

Comment: Loosely related: [Does “see you this weekend” in email express “will write another email this weekend”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3996/)

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer - I want to use the word "meet" because a face-to-face meeting would actually be a welcome outcome from my point of view. The consensus seems to be that this kind of usage of the word is acceptable if a bit unusual, so I'm going to go ahead and use it in this form. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: "The consensus" -- um, there was no such thing.

Answer (score 5):

"meeting" certainly can be applied to phone conversations, but "meet" by itself strongly implies a physical encounter; if you want to be neutral, don't use it. I would simply omit "meet to", and say "I hope we can discuss ... in the near future" -- that is neutral.

Comment: In the context of business conference calls **meeting** is fine. I wouldn't have a problem with saying later that I'd just **met** someone for the first time in such a call. Indeed, I **met** one of my closest friends in an internet chat room over a decade ago, and I've said as much to people who've asked about that ever since. But I certainly wouldn't use **meet** for a *future* online business discussion the way OP proposes. Even if it weren't actually misunderstood, it would probably raise an eyebrow.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said that *"meet" by itself strongly implies a physical encounter* and you have provided no reason to think otherwise. When you tell people that you met someone in a chat room, "meet" is no longer "by itself" -- the specification of a chat room makes it clear that the meeting was not in meat space. But without such specifiers, the connotations are as I stated. Reread the OP's question to see the context and the issue that was being addressed.

Comment: "Reread the OP's question to see the context and the issue that was being addressed" -- ah, you did ... and you agree, so your comment serves no purpose.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. My comment was intended to agree with and amplify your answer, and re-reading it now I can't see how I have failed to do that. Did you perhaps simply assume that any comment posted under an Answer must by definition be disputing that Answer? Or do you actually disagree with anything I said? I don't mind deleting my comments if you think they detract from your answer in some way, but I would like to know why.

Comment: "I don't really understand what you're saying" -- Sad. "I can't see how I have failed to do that" -- sadder still.

Comment: Snarky response over three years later -- as sad as it gets.

Comment: No, your response is sadder (mine actually was about something, whereas yours is just reflexive comeback). And my comment was not "snarky" -- another word that you don't understand the meaning of. As for the time gap ... unlike you, I don't camp out here. And besides, SE is forever. Anyway, I'm done with you ... until some future year when I stumble upon this again and am unfortunately reminded of your existence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a problem with that use of meeting. If it bothers you, you could always leave it out. Your sentence would make perfect sense without it.